# ASP.NET work and PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to use PDF file in the webpage. I want the PDF to open in a part of the Page. What code can I use? Can I use Panel? 
I know how to open the PDF in full webpage but I want to open the PDF in part of the page. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could render pdf file on part of your page using [object](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) or [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) HTML tags.

Comment: There is also a [tutorial](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/PDF-View-Custom-Control.aspx) on how to create custom ASP.NET control that will render pdf using `<iframe>`.

Comment: want i want to do is like what google did in Google Book how they appeared those book in the website

Comment: No problem :) Also you could take a look at this neat project: [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).

Comment: Just to be nit-picky, an `object` or `iframe` tag is still going to require the user to have a PDF reader installed. Granted, most users do, but it is not the same as Google Books. Google Books uses images.